# Ajax issue with Flask

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, python-3.x, flask

For the past few days I have been attempting to get an ajax call to work with Flask. No matter what I try nothing is working. So I will jump right into my code:

Python Code:

```
 @app.route("/num")
 def num():
     return render_template('num.html')

 @app.route('/add_num', methods=['POST'])
 def add_num():
    a = request.form['a']
    b = request.form['b']
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    print(a)
    if a and b:
      c = a + b 
      return jsonify(result = c)
    return jsonify({'error' : 'Missing Data'})
```

HTML Code

```
  <form>
     <input id='a' type="text" size="5" name="a"/> +
     <input id='b' type="text" size="5" name="b"/> =
     <br>
     <br>
     <button>Add It!</button>
  </form>

  <h1 id='result'>Result</h1>
```

Ajax Code:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $('form').bind('submit', function(event){
            $.ajax({
               data: {
                  a: $('#a').val(),
                  b: $('#b').val()
               },
               type: 'POST',
               url: '/add_num',
               dataType: 'json',
               data: JSON.stringify(json),
               contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
           })
            .done(function(data){
              if (data.error){
                $('#result').text(data.error).show();
              }else{
                $('#result').text(data.result).show();
              }
           });
        event.preventDefault();
        });
       });
      </script>
```

When I hit the submit button nothing happens. I will see this in the URL:
           http://127.0.0.1:5000/num?a=2&b=3
Also, at one point I was getting the numbers added but taken to a separate page that showed JSON information. To have that happen my top line of my form was this:

```
    <form action='add_num' method="post" role='form'>
```

Now I have tried to use a different format of ajax which works perfectly fine in my code. However, I want to try this method because I like it much better. I am fairly certain that the solution is something simple but I cannot track it down. Any help would be great!

This is what finally got it working for me:

```
`  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('form').bind('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
           $.ajax({
               data: {
                  a: $('#a').val(),
                  b: $('#b').val()
           },
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/add_num',
            success: function(data){
            $('#result').text(data.result).show();
        }
     });
   });
  });`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `event.preventDefault()` above your ajax call. If you saw `a` and `b` in the parameter string, that means the form is performing its default action.

EDIT: It could be that you two `data` keys in the object you're passing to `$.ajax` and that on the second `data` key you're calling `JSON.stringify` with a variable that doesn't seem to exist as a parameter.

Comment: Moving to above the ajax call leads to the same thing. I do not even believe that the data is getting to the Python code because I have a print(a) in the code and nothing is printing to the console.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: yeah I commented out the JSON.stringify portion and still the same issue. Thank you for you feed back Allie. I have been spending about 2 days on this of and on and not quite sure what the issue is! It is almost as if this form of ajax will not work...which makes no sense to me.

Comment: Is there no error printing in the console? I would add `debugger;` as the first line of your `submit` callback and step through it line by line.

Comment: Actually the only error that I am getting is the following: TypeError: $(...).on is not a function[Learn More] But I did not think it was an issue until now-I was watching a Youtube video on this and that was the same code that was in the video. Does it appear wrong?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Did you include it?

Comment: I am using 1.4.2 => <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> and it is included.

Comment: Allie, I got it and it appears to have been a combination of the Jquery version and the location of event.preventDefault(); It was your advice and help that eventually led me to the answer. I will fully update my solution in the morning. Thank you though!